# Relationship between entailment and equivalence with consistency

Tags: logic

If A entails B, why is it not true that A is also consistent with B? Given the definition requires A and B to be able to be true at the same time.

Comment: If A is itself inconsistent then it entails any proposition, including B. In which case, A and B are not consistent.

Comment: "The definition requires A and B to be able to be true at the same time", definition of what?

Answer (score 2):

If A is consistent and A entails B, then {A, B} is consistent.

If A is inconsistent, then A entails B, but {A, B} is not consistent.

Answer (score 2):

We can clarify a little bit the relationship between some fundamental logical concepts using their definitions.

In classical logic we have that **A** entails **B** (or : **B** is a [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) of **A**) iff **A → B** is *valid* (in propositional logic : is a *tautology*).

But a formula is *valid* iff its negation is [*unsatisfiable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability#Reduction_of_validity_to_satisfiability).

Thus, **A** entails **B** iff **¬ (A → B)** is unsatisfiable.

In turn, the formula **¬ (A → B)** is unsatisfiable iff the set of formulas **{ A, ¬B }** is *inconsistent*.

*Conclusion* :

> **A** entails **B** iff **{ A, ¬B }** is *inconsistent*.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to rephrase things as, "A entails B iff B is 'consistent relative to A:'" if A entails B, then any consistent set of sentences containing A *remains* consistent when we add B to it.

Entailment - like lots of mathematical notions - allows **vacuity**: if A is inconsistent, then since there are no models of A at all, it is vacuously true that every model of A is also a model of B ("all the elephants in this room are pink"). So this is why the "relative to A" clause above is important. Alternatively, we could say "If A entails B, then *either* {A,B} is consistent *or* the entailment is 'stupid' (= A entails B by virtue of A being false)."

Comment: For ease of readability I'm conflating a bit between "consistency" and "satisfiability" in the above; [they are in fact equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem), but this is a deep fact and I feel obliged to mention the issue.